# how to get hdfs filename with apache drill

Tags: hdfs, apache-drill

I want to get hdfs filename through drill to show, the apache drill user guide(https://drill.apache.org/docs/file-system-storage-plugin/) not written how to get it,  I need help

Comment: Please make sure you read this and try to improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: are you able to add hdfs plugin as mentioned in the drill user guide?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command

SHOW FILES [ FROM filesystem.directory_name | IN filesystem.directory_name ];

And for more detailed info visit this link :-
http://drill.apache.org/docs/show-files-command/